# Wordpress получить адрес или название ссылки. Contact-form-7

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Стоит wocoomerce
посредство contact form 7 реализована обратная связь. на каждый товар, можно задать вопрос. возможно ли получить ссылку или название товара, про который будет спрашивать человек, не заходя в товар, а из каталога ?
в гугл есть такое:

```
$('.zakaz').click(function()
{
titleService=$(this).attr('data-title-service');
$('.hide-title').val(titleService);
});
```

я добавил это в common js , а шорткод

```
[hidden title-service class:hide-title id:title-service]
```

но почему-то нифига. тапками не кидайтесь) неук
p.s. js код изменил название кнопки на своё конечно

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю вам не надо юзать js для этого. В cf7 есть специальные теги для email. https://contactform7.com/special-mail-tags/

- `[_post_title]` — Название страницы (только для постов и пост типов)
- `[_post_url]` — Урл страницы (только для постов и пост типов)

Пробуйте использовать событие submit:

```
$( '.your-form' ).on( 'submit', function() {
    var hideTitle = $( this ).find( '.hide-title' );
    if ( hideTitle.lenght() ) {
        var title = $( '.some-class-with-title' ).text();
        hideTitle.val( title );
    }
} );
```

Comment: Эти коды работают из поста, со странички каталога. где идет перечень товаров, они не работает и ничего не показывают

Comment: Понял) вы на фронте можете где-то взять эти данные?

Comment: нет, только через эту форму, по-крайней мере я так думаю

Comment: Добавил пример на js

Comment: я вот немного не понял, у вас в коде идет поиск чего  hide-title а как мне его прописать куда-то? я чего-то совсем не могу разобраться. у меня есть форма, есть обработка этой формы. как мне подвязать сюда еще и название или ссылку ?